# Write a recursive function to convert a given string into the number it represents

Tags: c++, string, recursion, integer

In this code, I want to convert the `string` into `integer` by using `recursive function` but it is giving output in negetive.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int convert1(string s) {
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        int i = s[0] - '0';
        return i;
    }

    int so = convert1(s.substr(0, s.length() - 1));
    int num = s[s.length()] - '0';
    int ans = so * 10 + num;
    return (int)ans;
}

int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << convert1(s) << endl;
}
```

Comment: `s[s.length()]` goes outside the boundaries of the string.

Comment: return strtol(s.c_str(), nullptr, 10); But if you want to write it as a recursive functio nfor whatever reason, the function has to call itself (that's what makes it recursive)

Comment: @Justin no use [`std::stol(s,...);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)  which takes a std::string as first argument, strtol is the "C" style function.

Comment: @PepijnKramer that is an option. I prefer functions that don't throw exceptions, but that's just me.

Comment: @Justin Not just you,  that's a good consideration. The systems I develop for can "pay the price" for exceptions, and I prefer exception safe/RAII based code. But  exceptions are not (yet) free (though that's being worked on in the committee ;) )

Comment: Thanks all of you! I got my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If you try printing `s[s.length()]` each time you call `convert1`, you'll see that it's printing `0`. And then you're subtracting the value of `'0'` (`48`) from that.

Let's say we try to convert `"12"`.

The length is *not* 1, so we call `convert1` on `"1"`.

That *is* of length 1, so we return `1`.

So, if `so` is `1`, and `s[s.length()]` is `0`, then `num` is `-48` and `so * 10 + num` evaluates to `1 * 10 - 48` which is `-38`.

For a two digit number input, you will always see the first digit times 10, minus 48. For a three digit number, you'll see (the first digit * ten minus 48) times 10 minus 48. This pattern continues on. If the first digit is large enough, it times 10 minus 48 creates a positive number. If that's large enough, positive numbers continue to propagate through the recursion. If they ever get smaller than 48, then once the result is negative, it will just get larger as a negative number the more recursive calls are made.

---

As opposed to the way you have done things, you can employ an accumulator parameter in `convert1`.

```
int convert1(string s, int acc=0) {
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        return acc * 10 + (s[0] - '0');
    }

    return convert1(s.substr(1, s.length() - 1), 
                    acc * 10 + (s[0] - '0'));
}
```

Each time the function is recursively called, we update the accumulator by multiplying it by ten and adding the value of the first digit, and update the string by taking the "tail" of the string.

Or better, but a little bit further from your original, we return the accumulator when the string is empty.

```
int convert1(string s, int acc=0) {
    if (s.empty()) return acc;

    return convert1(s.substr(1, s.length() - 1), 
                    acc * 10 + (s[0] - '0'));
}
```

The benefit of this tail recursion is that this function (if properly optimized by a decent compiler) can run in constant stack space. Though it's academic in this case as the `int` type will overflow before a stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way

```
int main()
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout << strtol(s.c_str(), nullptr, 10) << endl;
}
```

Recursive for some reason

```
int convert_string(const char* string, int length){
   if (length == 0) {
      return 0;
   }

   int output = string[0] - '0';
   output *= pow(10, length - 1);
   output += convert_string(&string[1], --length);
   return output;
}

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cout << convert_string(s.c_str(), s.length()) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This would benefit from explanation of where the OP went wrong, rather than just he correct answer.

Comment: In `strtol(s.c_str(), nullptr, 10)`I recommend taking advantage of the second parameter, the one that's currently a `nullptr`. It allow you to detect where the conversion ended, vital information if you're given a string like  *1234five*. The code should also check for range errors.

Comment: Avoid using `pow` here. `pow` works in floating point, so you might get a bit of fuzz that results in 99999.999999 instead of 100000, and that'll truncate to 99999. Multiply integers instead.

Comment: @user4581301 they are using the string container so I expect correct null termination. strtol also handles invalid conversions 1234five would return 0. But if you really want you could strtol(s.c_str(), s.end(), 10)

Comment: Regarding *1234five would return 0*, [afraid not.](https://godbolt.org/z/56q4acoaM)

Comment: Oh strtol does handle that, neato. Good job strtol author. Hence why we just use the libraries provided for us where possible

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the last digit

```
int num = s[s.length()] - '0';
```

you have an out-of-bounds access to the string. Changing that to

```
int num = s[s.length() - 1] - '0';
```

and your code works. Inefficiently.

You create a new substring in every recursion. There are 2 ways to improve on that:

1. make a helper function that makes a copy of the string and then calls the recursive function. The recursive function takes a `std::string & s` and then can use `s.pop_back()`. As a side benefit the helper function can easily deal with strings starting with '-'. You should have this helper anyway.
2. change the argument to `std::string_view` then it's just a reference into the string and substring will just shrink that reference. The string is never copied. That's actually the only change, just change `std::string` to `std::string_view` and done.

I think the `std::string_view` is the way to go but requires c++17. Combine that with the helper for dealing with '-'.

The next thing is `s[s.length() - 1]`, which can be written as `s.back()`. Safes a bit of typing and no risk of an off-by-one error.

Then your condition for terminating the recursion is overly complex. You can write

```
if (s.empty()) return 0;
```

instead at the cost of an extra recursion call. On the other hand this allows parsing "". Not sure which way is faster, the simpler test might balance the extra recursive call. I like it because it doesn't repeat the digit conversion code and is less to type.

Next, if you are using `std::string_view`, then the `s.substr(0, s.length() - 1)` expression can be changed to using `s.remove_suffix(1);`.

All combined this gives you:

```
int convert1(std::string_view s) {
    if (s.empty()) return 0;

    int num = s.back() - '0';
    s.remove_suffix(1);
    int so = convert1(s)
    int ans = so * 10 + num;
    return ans;
}
```

---

One more thing to consider but it's a complete rewrite of your algorithm:

Your recursion isn't tail recursive. This uses up stack space proportional to the length of the string. While for parsing an "int" this shouldn't be a problem it will be a problem for larger problems. Or if someone just enters a really big number "14654645656348756...65464".

To solve this you have to turn your algorithm around. Instead of chopping digits of at the end take them from the front like you would doing this iteratively:

```
int iterative_convert(const std::string &s) {
    int acc = 0;
    for (const auto c : s) acc = acc * 10 + (c - '0');
    return acc;
}
```

To make this recursive you have to pass the intermediate result as accumulator down the recursion. So it becomes this:

```
int convert1(std::string_view s, int acc = 0) {
    if (s.empty()) return acc;
    acc = 10 * acc + (s.front() - '0');
    return convert1(s.substr(1), acc);
}
```

Not sure how you came up with the back to front algorithm but front to back results in better code.

Note: Short of needing c++17, or if you prefer, you can also use `std::string::const_iterator` (requires passing s.cend() as extra argument) or good old `const char *p = s.c_str();`